# Multiple by statements in data step?

Tags: sas

I figured out the solution to my problem already, but I'd like to know what is happening exactly, and why, or maybe if there is a workaround to the following:

Suppose you have:

```
data test;
   length group $20.;
   subject=1; hours=0; group= 'hour 1'; output;
   subject=1; hours=1; group= 'hour 15'; output;
   subject=1; hours=2; group= 'hour 15'; output;
   subject=2; hours=0; group= 'hour 1'; output;
   subject=2; hours=1; group= 'hour 15'; output;
   subject=2; hours=2; group= 'hour 15'; output;
run;
```

And you are sorting on the hours first, then group because it is character and wouldn't properly sort otherwise.

```
proc sort data=test;
   by subject hours group;
run;
```

Now when you run this code to retrieve only the first record of each group:

```
data test2;
   set test;
   by subject hours group;
   if first.group;
run;
```

It will print each record.

I recently learned that 'When you use more than one variable in the BY statement; If the first/last variable linked to a primary BY-variable changes to 1, the first/last variable linked to the second BY-variable will also be changed to one.'.
So of course, because the hours variable changes, the first/last from group is also reset.

So 'why' is this code running fine?

```
data test2;
   set test;
   by subject group;
   if first.group;
run;
```

It seems a bit weird to have to leave out variables you sorted on, and it doesn't appear so flexible, you can't use a macro variable list as an input to sort and by statement in a data step for example...? If this is just the way it is, is there maybe another preferred way of doing these kind of operations? I can see myself making this error often, just copy pasting the list of sorting variables...

Comment: Your data doesn't get created correctly, did you fix that first?

Comment: This is a great reference with the pictures showing how a BY group works. You're considering them indepedent, but they're not. It's a nested group now. https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lrcon&docsetTarget=p0xu93fy5eemkyn1p6mj5elses7j.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Comment: I'm confused.  You say your last step is running fine.  Did you check your log?  When I run the code, I get an error because the data set is not sorted by `subject group`: "ERROR: BY variables are not properly sorted on data set WORK.TEST."

Comment: I'm sorry, I changed the script slightly to post here, and I forgot to specify the length statement in the data step.

Comment: @Reeza In the reference, the first example groups by zipcode; for different zipcode there can be the same state. In my example: For different hours, the group remains the same. This is done by choosing the hour variable as by variable in the sort step. In the data step however, I can't add the hour variable if I want to have the output as in test2...

Comment: So the BY statement doesn't check if the data is sorted correctly first but if it happens to encounter a record out of order it will complain. So in this case the data happens to be in the same order so it works but if it wasn't it wouldn't. This is a bit of a lucky coincidence for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a BY statement to generate FIRST. and LAST. variables for a grouped variable that is not actually sorted then use the NOTSORTED keyword on the BY statement.

For example you might want to order the data by HOUR and then group it by the STATUS so that you can find out at what hour they transitioned to that STATUS.

```
data have;
  input subject hour status $;
cards;
 1  0   C
 1  1   B
 1  2   B
 1  3   D
 2  0   A
 2  1   D
 2  2   D
;

data want ;
  set have ;
  by subject status notsorted;
  if first.status;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs    subject    hour    status

 1        1         0       C
 2        1         1       B
 3        1         3       D
 4        2         0       A
 5        2         1       D
```